# Excel: Identifying and counting sets

Tags: microsoft-excel

##### Summary: Trying to identify and count available 'sets' (of items) in Excel.

---

###### Main logic and requirements

• Imagine there are 6 slots or options: A, B, C, D, E, F
• To be a valid set, it must contain 1 item from 3 different sets, so in Test 1 for example:
  └ ✅ [A, B, C] or [A, C, F] would be valid sets
  └ ❌ however [A, A, B] would not be a valid, as it uses only uses A and B
• The table below gives two data sets or scenarios to consider
• The numbers represent the qty of each item/slot that you have (think of them as physical objects)
• Once you use an item in a set, the number ('qty available') would be reduced by 1 and so you would need to make further sets out of the what's remaining.

##### Sample data and examples

| Scenario | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Test 2 | - | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | - |

In **Test 1** it would be possible to make **5 sets**...
`[A,B,C]; [B,C,D]; [C,E,F]; [A,B,C]; [D,E,F]`

In **Test 2** it would be possible to make **2 sets**...
`[B,C,D]; [C,D,E]`

**Note (Test 1)**: It is possible to make other combinations of sets, such as: `[A,B,C] [A,B,C] [D,E,F] [D,E,F]` and `[B,C,D] [B,C,D] [A,E,F] [A,E,F]`, however as the set of 5 above is optimal (i.e. has 1 more set than either of these combinations), then this would be the goal / ideal output in Excel.

Also, just to clarify that I don't have any specific requirements on the make-up of sets if they are equivalent... e.g. Given 1 each of A,B,C,D,E,F - both option 1: `[A,B,C] [D,E,F]`, and option 2: `[A,C,E] [B,D,F]` (and others similar) would all be perfectly valid and acceptable to me.

PS: If it helps, think of it like "baking cakes". A, B, C are the different ingredients (e.g. sugar, butter, flour, etc) and the numbers in each column are how much ingredient you have. Any cake recipe is valid as long as it uses 1x of 3 different ingredients. Once an ingredient is used, the qty is reduced by 1. The goal is to bake as many cakes as possible using a given pile of ingredients.

###### Please can someone help me figure out the formula for how to work this out.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: Question updated after initial posting, thanks to [@Engineer-Toast](https://superuser.com/users/348859/engineer-toast) and [@Ron Rosenfeld](https://superuser.com/users/366681/ron-rosenfeld) for your comments and input.

Comment: You're talking about permutations, kind of. There have been several questions about that on SuperUser before but yours has a wrinkle in it. In addition, it looks like you could actually make 5 sets from test 1 if you're clever about it: `[A,B,C] ; [B,C,D] ; [C,E,F] ; [A,B,C] ; [D,E,F]`. How optimal of a solution do you want this to be?

Comment: Please clarify your logic. For example, in Test1, why not `B,C,D; B,C,D; A,E,F; A,E,F` or various other combinations?

Comment: Great spot @EngineerToast, (I had to check myself) but yes you are right! -- TBH, I initially just had "Test2" but this seemed a little anemic, so I added "Test1" on the fly, apologies!... Thanks for the info about permutations, I did do several searches for "sets" before posting (and couldn't really think how else to describe it), but will look into permutations. In the interim will update the question with your set calculation! Also, thanks Ron for your reply, hopefully my update following Toast's comment will clarify better.

Comment: I don't get it. In the first test, you have `[A,B,C]` twice. Why? And then you say `[B,C,D]; [B,C,D]; [A,E,F]; [A,E,F]` is valid as well? Why? Maybe this is a mathematical thing that just goes above my head. Is there a resource I can read to understand this?

Comment: @andrewb Think of Test1 as having 2 `A` values, 3 `B` values, 4 `C` values, etc. like they're physical objects. Now, how many sets of 3 can you make without having more than 1 of any particular type in that set?

Comment: @Martin There is a VBA solution but it would take effort to write. The outline of one (inefficient) solution would be to generate the list of values (Test2 would be `BCCDDE`), generate every possible permutation of those characters, then check each set of 3 characters to make sure there are no duplicates. Concatenate the passing sets and add them to a list / array / collection. Once you've checked every permutation, pick one of the longest entries in that list and output it. There may be a more efficient mathematics solution if all you want is the count of sets, not the actual contents.

Comment: @EngineerToast How would the set (before taking into account the number of each object) differ from just the ***combinations*** without repeats?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're right that considering combinations would be sufficient. I was thinking through how I would draft the solution and there I would permutations. There are several solutions, all of which would take a fair bit of work. I would encourage OP to work a bit further towards a solution (using my idea or not) and come back with smaller questions. The short answer is, so far as I know, there isn't an easy formulaic answer but there *is* a large VBA answer that's too big to expect someone else to write it.

Comment: @EngineerToast but then why is `B,C,D; B,C,D; A,E,F; A,E,F` valid for test one? There are only 2 of each letter in there but there are supposed to be 4 Cs and 3 Bs. I don't get it still... sorry I'm slow :D

Comment: @andrewb  Because you cannot make another set of three distinct objects from the  objects that are remaining.

Comment: @andrewb See the OP's edit for optimal solution.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all your input and suggestions!... @RonRosenfeld - Thanks for answering comments & explaining to others... For anyone that is still unclear. think of it as "baking cakes". A, B, C are the different ingredients (e.g. A:sugar, B:butter, C:icing, D:jam, E:eggs, F:flour) and the numbers in each column are the qty you have of each ingredient. Any cake recipe is valid as long as it uses 1x 3 different ingredients, and using say 3x Eggs would not be. Once an ingredient has been used, the qty available is reduced by one. Goal: bake as many cakes as possible. Hope that helps!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld @​andrewb - RE: "you cannot make another set of three distinct objects from the objects that are remaining"... Yes, absolutely. This is where in my initial post I got a little unstuck as after I mentally made ABC, ABC, DEF, DEF, I then had BCC leftover (which wasn't usable) hence originally thinking max possible sets was 4. @​EngineerToast's logic was great, but I missed it (so trying to code a formula or VBA to use logic that I myself miss is probably going to be tricky! )

Comment: RE: VBA solution [1 of 2] -- Sounds intriguing... I can write VBA but (if I am understanding the comments correctly) trying to work out ALL permutations or ALL combinations sounds horrific. I don't mind putting the effort in myself to try and flesh it out, but if anyone has some starter code / function outline to get me going that would be great! 

Comment: RE: Lamba solution [2 of 2] -- Hmmm, admittedly this *may* be the better option/route, however TBH I don't really understand Lambda (I have watched 2-3 videos on it, but not quite "got it")... That said, from that I've gathered, it is supposed to be useful for recursive/looping problems like this(?), especially where you need to count/modify as you loop e.g. "reducing column quantities as you use ingredients", is that right?... If so, then then I may try and look into lambda again, see if I can try and get my head round it this time. 

Comment: @andrewb Say you have letter blocks with duplicates of some letters. You start putting those blocks into groups. You don't want more than 1 of any letter block in each group. Depending on how you make your groups, you can make more or less groups total. If you start with `AEF`, `AEF`, `BCD`, `BCD`, then you're left with extra blocks: `B`, `B`, and `C`. You can't make another group because you'd have to put two `B` blocks in one group and that's not allowed. This is not the *best* solution (because you want as many groups as possible) but it is a *valid* solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to thank everyone for bearing with me here and explaining everything in detail. Just so your time on me wouldn't be completely wasted, I attemptd to solve this in VBA. I have no idea how I would go about making it a pure formula.

I added some comments to hopefully make the process understandable. I'm not 100% sure if it works as intended but, as far as I can tell, it outputs valid solutions for both test1 and test2 in the question.

```vb
Sub combinations()
    Dim test() As Variant, backup() As Variant, output As Collection
    test = Array(2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2) ' the test counts are specified here
    Set output = New Collection
    
    Dim hci As Integer
    Do While canMakeSet(test)
        For i = 0 To 2
            hci = highestCountIndex(test) 'get the slot with highest count
            output.Add hci 'output that slot
            test(hci) = test(hci) - 1 'decrement slot by 1
            test(hci) = test(hci) * -1 ' "disable" slot so the next item is guaranteed to come from a different one
        Next i
        
        test = reset(test) 're-enable all slots
    Loop
    Debug.Print outputString(output)
End Sub

Function combinationsFc(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    Dim test() As Variant, backup() As Variant, output As Collection
    If rng.Rows.Count <> 1 Or rng.Columns.Count <> 6 Then
        combinationsFc = "Wrong input range size"
        Exit Function
    End If
    test = Array(rng.Cells(1, 1), rng.Cells(1, 2), rng.Cells(1, 3), rng.Cells(1, 4), rng.Cells(1, 5), rng.Cells(1, 6))
    Set output = New Collection
    
    Dim hci As Integer
    Do While canMakeSet(test)
        For i = 0 To 2
            hci = highestCountIndex(test) 'get the slot with highest count
            output.Add hci 'output that slot
            test(hci) = test(hci) - 1 'decrement slot by 1
            test(hci) = test(hci) * -1 ' "disable" slot so the next item is guaranteed to come from a different one
        Next i
        
        test = reset(test) 're-enable all slots
    Loop
    combinationsFc = outputString(output)
End Function

Function outputString(ByVal col As Collection) As String
    'this will just print out the output collection in a readable manner
    Dim val As String, letters As Variant
    letters = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
    outputString = "["
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        val = letters(col(i))
        If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            outputString = outputString & val & "]; ["
        Else
            outputString = outputString & val & ", "
        End If
    Next i
    outputString = Left(outputString, Len(outputString) - 3)
End Function

Function canMakeSet(ByVal arr As Variant) As Boolean
    'determines whether creating a set is possible by counting how many "slots" with at least one element are left
    'If there is at least 3, you can make a set
    canMakeSet = False
    Dim val As Integer, counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) > 0 Then counter = counter + 1
    Next i
    If counter >= 3 Then canMakeSet = True
End Function

Function highestCountIndex(ByVal arr As Variant) As Integer
    'determines the slot with highest count, element from this slot will be used next in a set
    highestCountIndex = LBound(arr)
    Dim val As Integer
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        val = arr(i)
        If val > arr(highestCountIndex) Then highestCountIndex = i
    Next i
End Function

Function reset(ByVal arr As Variant) As Variant
    'I "disable" slots that are already in a set by turning them negative
    'this function resets all negative slots back to positive
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Math.Abs(arr(i))
    Next i
    reset = arr
End Function
```

You can either just run the "combinations" sub to get the output in the immediate window, or use the "combinationsFc" function in your worksheet like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you can "pack" your sets with a list of items by going through the item list one at a time, here is a formula that (I think) works when none of items are over the count of `int(sum(items)/3)`:

`=CHOOSECOLS(WRAPCOLS(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(B1:G1&",",B2:G2)),,",",TRUE),INT(SUM(B2:G2)/3)),1,2,3)`

Starting with the insde:

- REPT: repeats the text the number of items & adding the comma (to create the item list)
- CONCAT: joins the list
- TEXTSPLIT: splits the list into cells by the comma
- WRAPCOLS: converts the 1D array into a 2D array the wrapping is determined by the `INT(SUM())`
- CHOOSECOLS: gets the first 3 columns (the fourth column occurs when `INT(SUM()` is not divisible by 3.

Caveats:

- I did not fully test
- as mentioned above this will only work when no particular item is more than than 1/3 the sum of the item count (I'm guessing you'll need a lamda function to do when you have item counts more than 1/3)
- it only gives one possible set. I'm sure that by changing how the items are packed you can get other sets.
- I'm sure there are other formula combinations that would be easier than what I created.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this wiki as it is only an intermediate step that may or may not help someone trying to craft a formula solution.

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,TRIM(REPT(B$1:G$1&" ",B2:G2)))," ","|",FALSE),""))
```

This formula can create a table that consists of the correct number of each letter separated by column. If you have some formula that's based on combining columns, this may be helpful. You could use something like `=LET(table,TRANSPOSE(~)...` to store this as a variable upon which you could perform other operations.

[image: Screenshot]